# How to stop url from adding to it when changing language

Tags: php, html, session

I got a link which provides the get value for my session. This way I check what language session is set. The problem is, when I click the link twice, it just adds to the url.

For example:

```
<?
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
?>
<a href="<? echo $actual_link; ?>?lang=en" class="btn-selector">EN</a>
```

Will result in: `website.nl?lang=en` when I click it once, but `website.nl?lang=en?lang=en` when I click it twice. How can I check for that and prevent it from happening?

Comment: you can try for `target = "_blank"` attribute for forcing to open new tab

Comment: @gaurav That's not very userfriendly

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` includes the query string, so you're echoing the whole thing, and then appending the language to it again. Try `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` instead.

Comment: I have the same issue if I use that.

Comment: You shouldn't; PHP_SELF should return just the file name. Try `$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/".basename(__FILE__);`